# Adding a Coordinate System - Three Axes to a Tree Element

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to add some features to the current three-dimensional tree element.

[image]

I would like to

1. label the three unlabeled nodes as (i, j - 1, k), (i, j, k) and (i, j + 1, k). I tried but they are too big to be fitted in and messed up the tree.
2. draw dotted lines from (i, j, k - 1) to (i, j, k + 1); and from (i, j - 1, k) to (i, j + 1, k).
3. add three axes (maybe blue) - x ,y ,z and three values on each axis that correspond to the nodes.

So that the result might look like this:

[image]

Many thanks!  I am using the code from this answer:

- [How to Create a Three Dimensional Probability Tree with Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/389916/2693)

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, quotes, shapes.geometric}
% Code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/389916/2693

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 6mm and 22mm,
dot/.style = {circle, fill = black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt, node contents={}},
every label/.style = {inner sep=1pt, font=\footnotesize}
]
\node (t) [trapezium,
fill=gray!20, draw, dashed,
minimum width=44mm, minimum height=11mm,
rotate=-90] {};%shape border

%
\node (r01)[dot,below left=of t.south,
label=above left:{$(i, j, k)$}];
%
\node (r11)[dot, at={(t.bottom left corner)},
label=60:{$(i, j - 1, k + 1)$}];
\node (r12)[dot, at={(t.west)},
label=60:{$(i, j , k + 1)$}];
\node (r13)[dot, at={(t.top left corner)},
label=60:{$(i, j + 1 , k + 1)$}];
%
\node (r21)[dot, at={(t.south)}];
\node (r22)[dot, at={(t.center)}];
\node (r23)[dot, at={(t.north)}];

%
\node (r31)[dot, at={(t.bottom right corner)},
label=-60:{$(i, j - 1, k - 1)$}];
\node (r32)[dot, at={(t.east)},
label=-60:{$(i, j , k - 1)$}];
\node (r33)[dot, at={(t.top right corner)},
label=-60:{$(i, j  + 1, k - 1)$}];
%


\draw[->]
(r01) edge [sloped] (r11)
(r01) edge [sloped] (r12)
(r01) edge [sloped] (r13)
%
(r01) edge [sloped] (r21)
(r01) edge [sloped] (r22)
(r01) edge [sloped] (r23)
%
(r01) edge [sloped] (r31)
(r01) edge [sloped] (r32)
(r01) edge [sloped] (r33)
;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use code from another answer on the site, it's good practice to refer to that question in the new question. I've added that to your question.

Comment: @AlanMunn `forest-3d`?!

Comment: I suggest using `tikz-3dplot` to do the heavy-lifting if this is going to get complicated. If it is really just 2d, probably not needed. If you need real 3d, something other than Ti*k*Z. (But you don't seem to need the last of these, at least.)

Comment: All the nodes are named, so you can just add whatever lines you want, can't you? What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Dotted lines to where? You only say from where.

Comment: Sorry I have edited the question.